# How to convert the following list of lists into list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, data-structures

I have the following list of lists.

```
[["172.27.219.11", "First_Host", 13L, Decimal("44.8276")]
 ["172.27.219.11", "Second_Host", 16L, Decimal("55.1724")]
 ["172.27.241.210", "Second_Host", 19L, Decimal("100.0000")]
 ["52.11.201.64", "First_Host", 30L, Decimal("3.9164")]
 ["52.11.201.64", "Second_Host", 736L, Decimal("96.0836")]]
```

I have to group them by the ip_addresses. So for instance for the first ip_address `172.27.219.11` , I have to group the `First_Host` , `Second_Host` and their respective decimal values as traffic . If the IP address is not repeated then just add that. So essentially after doing for the above example I should get it as.

```
[
    {
        "ip" : "172.27.219.11",
        "value": [
                    {
                        "name" : "First_Host",
                        "traffic" : 44.8276,
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Second_Host",
                        "traffic": 55.1724,
                    }
                ]
        "ip" : "172.27.241.210"
        "value": [
                    {
                        "name": "Second_Host",
                        "traffic": 100 ,
                    }

               ]
        "ip": "52.11.201.64"
        "value": [
                    {
                        "name": "Second_Host",
                        "traffic": 3.9164,
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "First_Host",
                        "traffic": 96.0836,
                    }

               ]

    }
]
```

I need help in formulating the response in the said format please.

Comment: You have a dictionary with the multiple instances of the same key (`ip` and `value`) in your example output. That won't be possible. Also here on SO we like to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Okay , so is there a better way to structure it apart from the dictionary to get what I want.

Comment: The depends on what you want to do with the data and how you want to access it. If you want to access a dataset by IP you should use the IP as the key and the dataset as the value. putting both into the `ip` and `value` field will complicate accessing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
raw_data = [["172.27.219.11", "First_Host", 13L, Decimal("44.8276")],
 ["172.27.219.11", "Second_Host", 16L, Decimal("55.1724")],
 ["172.27.241.210", "Second_Host", 19L, Decimal("100.0000")],
 ["52.11.201.64", "First_Host", 30L, Decimal("3.9164")],
 ["52.11.201.64", "Second_Host", 736L, Decimal("96.0836")]]



final = [{'ip':j} for j in list(set([i[0] for i in raw_data]))]

for i in raw_data:
    for j in final:
        if i[0]== j['ip']:
            if j.has_key('value'):
                j['value'].append({'name':i[1],'traffic':float(i[3])})
            else:
                j['value'] = []
                j['value'].append({'name':i[1],'traffic':float(i[3])})
```